# Find/Replace an Inserted Check Box Symbol with a Check Box Content Control

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to find/replace all inserted check box symbols with checkbox content controls. The symbol's font is Wingdings (either 111 or 168). Below is the code I started with, but I hit a wall when I realized that Word find doesn't recognize the symbol. I appreciate any help or guidance. Thank you.

```
Sub ReplaceUnicode168()
    Dim objContentControl As ContentControl
    With ActiveDocument
      Set objContentControl = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlCheckBox)
        objContentControl.Cut
        With Selection.Find
          .ClearFormatting
          .Replacement.ClearFormatting
          .Forward = True
          .Wrap = wdFindContinue
          .MatchCase = False
          .MatchWholeWord = True
          .MatchWildcards = False
          .Text = Chr(168)
          .Replacement.Text = "^c"
          .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you try to find/replace these two particular characters using

```
.Text = ChrW(61551)
```

for the "111" WingDings Character and

```
.Text = ChrW(61608)
```

for the "168" WingDings character.

Be aware that the way Word encodes these characters is not very helpful. As far as Find/Replace is concerned, you have to use these Unicode Private Use Area encodings.

If you actually select the character and use VBA to discover its code using e.g.

```
Debug.Print AscW(Selection)
```

the answer is always 40 (and the Font of the character will probably be the same as the Surrounding font) Pretty useless. In older versions of Word you used to be able to look for the 40 character and find these characters, but I don't think that's possible now. But if you select the character and use

```
Sub SymInfo()
With Dialogs(wdDialogInsertSymbol)
  ' You won't see .Font and .CharNum listed under the
  ' properties of a Word.Dialog - some older Dialogs add
  ' per-Dialog properties at runtime.
  Debug.Print .Font
  Debug.Print .CharNum
End With
End Sub
```

Then you get the font name (Wingdings in this case) and the private use area character number, except it's expressed as a negative number (-3928 for Wingdings 168). The character to use in the Find/Replace is 65536-3928 = 61608.

Alternatively, you can find the private use area code by selecting the character, getting its WordOpenXML code, then finding the XML element that gives the code (and the font). Ideally use MSXML to look for the element but the following gives the general idea.

```
Sub getSymElement
Dim finish As Long
Dim start As Long
Dim x As String
x = Selection.WordOpenXML
start = Instr(1,x,"<w:sym")
' Should check for start = 0 (not found) here.
finish = Instr(start,x,">")
Debug.Print Mid(x,start, finish + 1 - start)
```

and for the 168 character you should see something like

```
<w:sym w:font="Wingdings" w:char="F0A8"/>
```

(Hex F0A8 is 61608)

There may be a problem where Word could potentially map more than one font/code to the same unicode private use area codepoint. There is some further code by Dave Rado [here](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/FindReplaceSymbols.htm) but I do not think you will need it for this particular problem.

After some follow-up, the following seems to work reasonably well here:

```
Sub replaceWingdingsWithCCs()
Dim cc As Word.ContentControl
Dim charcode As Variant
Dim ccchecked As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Word.Range

' Make sure the selection point is not in the way
' (If the selection contains one of the characters you are trying to
' replace, Word will raise an error about the selection being in a
' plain text content control.

' If the first item in the document is not a CC,
' it's enouugh to do this:

ActiveDocument.Select
Selection.Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart

' Put the character codes you need to look for here. Maybe you have some checked boxes too?
charcode = Array(61551, 61608)
' FOr each code, say whether you want a checked box (True) or an unchecked one.
ccchecked = Array(False, False)

For i = LBound(charcode) To UBound(charcode)
  Set r = ActiveDocument.Range
  With r.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    With .Replacement
      .ClearFormatting
      .Text = ""
    End With
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Text = ChrW(charcode(i))
    Do While .Execute(Replace:=True)
      Set cc = r.ContentControls.Add(WdContentControlType.wdContentControlCheckBox)
      cc.Checked = ccchecked(i)
      r.End = r.Document.Range.End
      r.Start = cc.Range.End + 1
      Set cc = Nothing
    Loop
  End With
Next
Set r = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you! The only side effect is it adds a paragraph after replacing the symbol. I tried concatenating a space, but the object doesn't support this. How do you write the code to avoid this? Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up message. Prior to using macros, I learned to select the CC as you described. I then wrote a simple procedure to insert the CC but included a space. The code I used below the CC.Add was Selection.MoveRight two Characters, then below it, added a space using the typetext. Is there a way to add the space to the "^c"? Thanks again.

Comment: After another test, I noticed it only adds the paragraph if symbol is placed by itself one paragragh at a time, like bullet points. However, when I ran the macro when the symbol is part of a sentence, it did not add the paragrah.

Comment: Yes and no. It's a bit erratic as it worked error free testing once, but when I ran it again on another document with the same symbols, it removed text in between symbols as it placed CCs. Other times it ignored some symbols while successfully replacing others. This got me thinking that maybe it'd best to use a loop with a conditional IF where IF Dialogs(wdDialogInsertSymbol) = (symbol) then... I reluctantly admit that I'm still very new at this and not sure how to write the code. I found the "Dialogs(wdDialogInsertSymbol)" on another post, but I don't recall which one to properly citre it.

Comment: Oh yeah, that worked. Thank you very much! Also, thanks for adding the notes. This helps me understand what the code is looking for as it runs. Thanks again!

Comment: I'll be mindful of providing feedback on this forum going forward. It's the least I could do for the time you (and others) spend helping me sort problems like this one out. This macro has saved me a tremendous amount of time, so thank you again for that!

Comment: @SingleMattScott FWIW I enjoyed it, and I found out stuff too. Lots of people try to answer questions and put time and effort into checking what works and what does not. But they can't know whether that just worked for them or works more generally, until someone gets back and says "it worked for me". O&O for now!